# What is the cause of this Sphinx autodoc MockFinder error?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am creating documentation with Sphinx. My folder structure looks as follows:

```
MyProject
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mycode.py
│   └── etc.
└── docs
    ├── build
    ├── make.bat
    ├── Makefile
    └── source
       ├── conf.py
       ├── index.rst
       ├── _static
       └── _templates
```

I begin by running `make clean` and `make html` in the `docs` directory. Next, to populate the documentation, I run `sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ../mypackage`, and all corresponding `.rst` files are generated as expected. Finally, I run `make clean` and `make html` once more to ensure a clean build, as suggested in the [Sphinx-RTD-Tutorial](https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-the-docs.html#finalising-the-documentation). However, on this final build, I get the following output:

```
Running Sphinx v4.0.2
making output directory... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: index.rst, mypackage.rst, mypackage.mycode.rst

Extension error (sphinx.ext.autosummary):
Handler <function process_generate_options at 0x10678dee0> for event 'builder-inited' threw an exception (exception: list.remove(x): x not in list)
make: *** [html] Error 2
```

Removing the autosummary extension and just running autodoc with the same sequence of commands leads to a similar error:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc/mock.py", line 151, in mock
    sys.meta_path.remove(finder)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Here is the source code method that the error comes from:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def mock(modnames: List[str]) -> Generator[None, None, None]:
    """Insert mock modules during context::

        with mock(['target.module.name']):
            # mock modules are enabled here
            ...
    """
    try:
        finder = MockFinder(modnames)
        sys.meta_path.insert(0, finder)
        yield
    finally:
        sys.meta_path.remove(finder)
        finder.invalidate_caches()
```

Does anyone know what might be raising this error or have an idea as to what is happening in this method? Could it have to do with my specification of `sys.path` in my `conf.py` file?

```
[conf.py]

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../mypackage'))
```

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I assume that it tries to create `finder`, but fails, then you try to remove what does not exist in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error using the [autodoc_mock_imports](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports) config:

> **autodoc_mock_imports**
> This value contains a list of modules to be
> mocked up. This is useful when some external dependencies are not met
> at build time and break the building process. You may only specify the
> root package of the dependencies themselves and omit the sub-modules:
>
> ```
> autodoc_mock_imports = ["django"]
> ```
>
> Will mock all imports under the django package.
>
> *New in version 1.3.*
>
> *Changed in version 1.6:* This config value only requires to declare the
> top-level modules that should be mocked.